# Disable manage stock configuration Magento does not work

Tags: magento-1.9, inventory

I am migrating an existing Magento site to a new install.

I imported about 10000 products which all use 'stock config' settings. When i try to change the config setting 'manage stock' to NO, it loads for a while and says 'config saved', but the setting remains YES. All other settings do work. Only not the Manage stock setting.

[image: If I change Manage stock to No and save it switches back to Yes]

How can I disable the setting through database or back-end?

Greetings,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this query.

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value=0 
WHERE `path` = 'cataloginventory/item_options/manage_stock';
```

Comment: The products settings are good, it is about the config setting. thx do!

Comment: i've edited my answer

Comment: Thx, but this is a product setting is it not? I want to change only the config setting as shown above.

Comment: got ur point. Please check the updated answer